# Spring STS (New Server Wizard)

Tags: spring, tomcat, wizard, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

The following is being experienced within Spring STS: In the process of Defining a New Server, the Server name is not populating for me to be able to click 'Next'. Previous to this, I selected Tomcat v7.0 Server, while desiring to get the most recent Tomcat server. This may have inadvertently been deleted rather than deselected in the process of learning how to overcome an error such as this:

*"Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /// the configuration may be corrupt or incomplete ~/conf/catalina.policy".*

Attempted resolve: When I click on Tomcat v6.0 Server, the Server name field populates with 'Tomcat v6.0 Server at localhost'. I attempted to manually type an entry of 'Tomcat v7.0 at localhost' yesterday, but does not work. It seems it has nothing close to it to find, not even default. I would like to understand how I can re-establish what I originally had. Although I will still need to overcome the error message that I encountered which may have led to me inadvertently deleting a pointing mechanism to what was Tomcat 7.

I am installing this on Linux. It is difficult to find definitive resolve.

**What is a remedy that makes sense - for being able to then get apache-tomcat-7.0.xx (most recent) to be recognized?**

Comment: Do you have any relevant errors in your error log?  Go to Window -> Show view -> Other -> Error log. Paste them here.

Comment: eclipse.buildId=3.2.0.201303060821-RELEASE-e42
java.version=1.7.0_12-ea
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.springsource.sts.ide
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product org.springsource.sts.ide

Comment: Error
Mon Apr 29 13:35:13 CDT 2013
Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.

Comment: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
 at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat70Configuration.load(Tomcat70Configuration.java:313)

Comment: at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.getTomcatConfiguration(TomcatServer.java:124)
 at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getTomcatConfiguration(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:80)

Comment: at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.publishServer(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:233)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:975)

Comment: at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
 at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

Comment: Next time, it would be better to edit your question with the stack trace. It's hard to read as comments.  Or you can even add it to pastebin and provide a link.

Comment: Sorry about that Andrew. Neat tool, Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/pHHQ4ATE  (If you cannot access that view, please inform.) If there is not a relatively quick/easy fix to this I may re-do all this from scratch or start looking into JBoss instead (as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like Tomcat server 7 wasn't set up properly.  Have you followed these instructions?

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html

Comment: I am starting from scratch with Linux.

Answer (score 1):

try this:
go to window->preferences->server->runtime environments->click remove apache tomcat.
then reinstall your tomat

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Linux Mint 17.3 and Spring Tools Suite.  I would create a new server and click "run on server" for my dynamic web project.  It would work one time and then I would get the same error you are getting this caused a great deal of frustration at work.
 
I have now SOLVED the issue.
1) create a new Pivotal TC Server v3.0-v3.1 
2) give your host a name or keep all the defaults 
3) create new instance 
4) name the instance and use the "base" template 
5) the next page is where I had the issue!! 
6) Please enter the user account that should start the instance when using the bin/init.d.sh script.  by default "tcserver" is in there and I had always just clicked next.  Do NOT do that.  erase tcserver and put your username that you log into when you start your computer. 
 
now my server runs without errors.  hope this saves some people from the frustration I experienced.